# Unable to specify a union of conditions for subsetting a array

Tags: matlab

I wish to subset a 1-d array 1332x1, whereby the values lie between given three ranges. I am able to do so for single range only. In case, of three ranges  I get the following error. 
I can't append for obvious reasons.  (The resultant 1-d array is binary represent 1 for the satisfied elements and zero for others.)

```
filter2= ((pe<15 & pe >5) or (pe<35 & pe >25) or (pe<65 & pe >55));
```

> filter2= ((pe<15 & pe >5) or (pe<35 & pe >25) or (pe<65 & pe >55));
>                              | Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
filter2= ((pe<15 & pe >5) | (pe<35 & pe >25) | (pe<65 & pe >55));
```